# Constant cumulative sum of repetitions for multiple characters in regex (python)

Tags: python, regex

I would like to search for the expression that starts with 1, 2 or 3 digits, and then continues with a combination of spaces  and dashes `-`. However, the length of the expression must be at most 4 characters, giving the possible combinations of the following sort: '123- ', '1 - ', '66 -' etc. I'm sure the question already has an answer somewhere, but I can't seem to formulate my problem concisely enough to find anything.

In short, a formulation of the following kind would be ideal: `[0-9]{1,3}[ -]{1,3}{{4}}` where the `4` indicates that the total sum should not exceed 4.

Of course, I can always type `[0-9][ -]{3}|[0-9]{2}[ -]{2}|[0-9]{3}[ -]`, but, as much as it gets the job done in this scenario, it would quickly become a headache to list all the individual cases for longer sets of characters.

Comment: Try `String regex = "\\b\\d{1,3}[ -]{1,3}(?<=\\b\\d[\\d -]{3})";`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/xFlate)

Comment: That does the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
String regex = "\\b\\d{1,3}[ -]{1,3}(?<=\\b\\d[\\d -]{3})";
```

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (may be replaced with `(?<!\d)` if the numbers can be glued to letters or `_`)
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `[ -]{1,3}` - 1 to 3 spaces or hyphens
- `(?<=\\b\\d[\\d -]{3})` -  a positive lookbehind that requires that, immediately to the left of the current location, there must be a digit, and then 3 digits, spaces or hyphens.

See this [Java demo](https://ideone.com/xFlate).

```
String s = "123-      1 -  66 -  ";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{1,3}[ -]{1,3}(?<=\\b\\d[\\d -]{3})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("'" + matcher.group(0) + "'"); 
}
```

Output:

```
'123-'
'1 - '
'66 -'
```